# How to fixed framework errors?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I am using lot of frameworks and pod files in my project like as Parse framework, Bolts Framework etc. and I have fixed all errors like `parse.h` file not found and any others but now I have some error also like ....

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Crain/iOS Apps/crain_comm_ios/crainmagazine/common/Brightcove-3.0.1/Libraries'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Crain/iOS Apps/crain_comm_ios/frameworks/Flurry'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Crain/iOS Apps/crain_comm_ios'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Crain/iOS'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-FApps/crain_comm_ios'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-FApps/crain_comm_ios/frameworks'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-FApps/crain_comm_ios/frameworks/Parse.framework'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F2'
ld: library not found for -lBCiOSSDK
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

so can you please tell me answer or any solution.

Answer (score 1):

Some times the device that u compile the project is using 64bit. In debug mode the pod projects in some architecture aren't even complie, U should do this:

See my selections (set it to NO in both modes debug and release) :
[image]

Comment: Hi gran, I do this already but compiler show same error  linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) with directory warnings show above.

Comment: The warning aren't change much. It can appear because of multiple developers that touch your project.

Comment: Try to delete the pod project (via the finder and NOT via the xcode) and `pod install` once again

Answer (score 0):

warning: directory not found for option - you should fix that problems, linker could not find libraries, I think, you add add headers, but not libraries.